# No audio from VLC or from Mozilla + Flash

Tags: sound, vlc, flash

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit) with VLC 1.1.5.

When I play any content (audio/video) in VLC, I don’t hear any audio. The same thing happens with Flash content playing in Mozilla.

I tried to install `vlc-plugin-esd`, but I am getting the error “package not found”.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu (specifically GNOME) doesn't use ESD anymore, the default is pulseaudio. So in order to make audio output work in VLC you have to install vlc-plugin-pulse and set the audio output option in VLCs preferences to "pulse".

As for your problem with Mozilla, try using the native 64bit version of Adobes flash plugin rather than the 32bit version using nspluginwrapper.

You can get the 64bit version here:
https://launchpad.net/~sevenmachines/+archive/flash

Comment: I tried the command `sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-pulse` and i got a message saying `it is already installed and upto date`..I ran the command `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins "pulseaudio-*" paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter` it is successfully installed..Changed the audio preferences to pulse in VLC... **Still i dont hear any sound from VLC**.. From other player it is working fine..Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

See Known Issues section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio

Comment: As mentioned in the link `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins "pulseaudio-*" paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter` I ran this command..still i dont hear any audio from VLC..    **Anything i have to do ?**   Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try **rm -fr ~/.pulse** then reboot.